# Precompiling assets failed. while deploying on heroku

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, deployment

while deploying to heroku iam getting this error.This is my first time deployement so any help is appriciated.

```
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        ExecJS::RuntimeError: SyntaxError: Unexpected character '#'
remote:        JS_Parse_Error.Object.defineProperty.get ((execjs):3538:621)
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:47:in `rescue in block in call'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:44:in `block in call'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:75:in `block in lock'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:73:in `Locker'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:73:in `lock'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:43:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/uglifier-3.1.9/lib/uglifier.rb:190:in `run_uglifyjs'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/uglifier-3.1.9/lib/uglifier.rb:152:in `compile'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:53:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:28:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:134:in `block in find'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:133:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:133:in `find'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:185:in `compile'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:68:in `block (3 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        V8::Error: Unexpected character '#'
remote:        at js_error (<eval>:3623:12181)
remote:        at parse_error (<eval>:3623:14198)
remote:        at next_token (<eval>:3623:19758)
remote:        at next (<eval>:3623:21695)
remote:        at <eval>:3623:23768
remote:        at <eval>:3623:22771
remote:        at <eval>:3624:3495
remote:        at parse (<eval>:3624:3735)
remote:        at parse (<eval>:3959:22)
remote:        at uglifier (<eval>:4007:13)
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:45:in `block in call'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:75:in `block in lock'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:73:in `Locker'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:73:in `lock'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:43:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/uglifier-3.1.9/lib/uglifier.rb:190:in `run_uglifyjs'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/uglifier-3.1.9/lib/uglifier.rb:152:in `compile'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:53:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:28:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:134:in `block in find'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:133:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:133:in `find'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:185:in `compile'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:68:in `block (3 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_0cc559ca757e781035a2d51391cb0258/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to laundryapp-aaquib.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/laundryapp-aaquib.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

I removed all the cofee script file which are created by scaffold and replaced them with ".js" extention and also deleted which i dont needed.i also replaced my application.css to application.css.scss.I also tried
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=development and the same in production but got the same error as above.Iam also getting this when pushing to heroku
 Important: You may need to add a javascript runtime to your Gemfile in order for bootstrap's LESS files to compile to CSS.

Comment: Try comment out all assets js and css.  Then uncomment 1 file at at time and run precompile.  This should lead you to which file has compilation errors.  Then search that file for the `#`. Or in your editor full text search that assets/ path for `#` It's probably a typo somewhere.  If you're using ERB inside JS that can also cause problems.

Comment: as It is a demo app,it does not have much css and js. still I commented all the js and css.except the plugins but still the same error is comming and what do you mean by erb inside js?

Comment: Does rake assets:precompile working?

Comment: yes .see what iam getting.I, [2017-10-18T17:42:03.228754 #7221]  INFO -- : Writing /home/aaquib/Desktop/applications/Laundryapp/public/assets/backend-14ce09d71ef06bf94dcdc7b08326d779accbacc2b41f3807d56385dcff44cac2.css

Comment: I, [2017-10-18T17:42:03.230146 #7221]  INFO -- : Writing /home/aaquib/Desktop/applications/Laundryapp/public/assets/backend-14ce09d71ef06bf94dcdc7b08326d779accbacc2b41f3807d56385dcff44cac2.css.gz
I, [2017-10-18T17:42:04.298197 #7221]  INFO -- : Writing /home/aaquib/Desktop/applications/Laundryapp/public/assets/backend-c6ef96665dee7aece8ca415215bf3d0f7db2d753e6562b28bd107c0cd892235e.js

Comment: I, [2017-10-18T17:42:04.298458 #7221]  INFO -- : Writing /home/aaquib/Desktop/applications/Laundryapp/public/assets/backend-c6ef96665dee7aece8ca415215bf3d0f7db2d753e6562b28bd107c0cd892235e.js.gz

Comment: If you remove all coffee script, also maybe try to remove coffee gem
remove `gem "coffee-script"` from Gemfile or comment and run `bundle install`